# Bug in kazoo 2.0 library

Tags: python, kazoo

I am using kazoo in project I am working on. But after some time I get an error message that new connection to zookeper cannot be opened.

So I wrote a little test program:

```
for i in range(0, 1000):
    print i

    zk = kazoo.client.KazooClient()
    zk.start()
    zk.stop()
```

And after around 500 iteration I've got an error: "Too many open files".

Am I using kazoo somehow wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the `close()` method.  From the [documentation](http://kazoo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/client.html):

> `close()`
>
> Free any resources held by the client.
>
> This method should be called on a stopped client before it is
>   discarded. Not doing so may result in filehandles being leaked.
>
> New in version 1.0.

However the example code within the same documentation doesn't call `close()`, so it's confusing.